# Getting request URL in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to know the difference between the below two methods of getting a request URL in servlet.

Method 1:

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

Method 2:

```
url = request.getScheme()
      + "://"
      + request.getServerName()
      + ":"
      + request.getServerPort()
      + request.getRequestURI();
```

Are there any chances that the above two methods will give two different URLs?

Answer (score 80):

The [`getRequestURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) omits the port when it is 80 while the scheme is `http`, or when it is 443 while the scheme is `https`.

So, just use `getRequestURL()` if all you want is obtaining the entire URL. This does however not include the GET query string. You may want to construct it as follows then:

```
StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
    requestURL.append("?").append(request.getQueryString());
}
String completeURL = requestURL.toString();
```