# How to retrieve URL with parameters from a servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

If a user goes to `profile?id=20`, using `request.getPathInfo()` just returns `/profile`. Is there a way to retrieve the whole URL with parameters?

The reason I need to know this is because I want to forward the user back to the exact same page they came from after invoking a command, for example a `friend request command`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting request URL in a servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040094/getting-request-url-in-a-servlet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not part of the path info.

You need to get it by [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29).

```
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
// ...
```

And then compose the new URL yourself based on the parts.

By the way, I don't see why you would need it in a forward as the initial URL would remain the same. Perhaps you're confusing it with redirect?

Comment: my `commands` require an url (`request.getPathInfo().substring(1)`) to be returned, then my `FrontController` checks if it equals the current view and if it is equal it uses `dispatcher.forward` and if it isn't equal it uses `response.sendRedirect`. The problem with `request.getPathInfo().substring(1)` is it won't go back to a page with parameters.

Comment: OK, you're indeed sending a redirect, not a forward. Just add `request.getQueryString()` to the redirect URL if necessary.