# How can I let a server sense which domain name it is serving?

Tags: java, servlets, dns

I have a Java Servlet container. This servlet container may serve `localhost:8080`, `192.168.1.2:8080`, `www.development.example` or `www.production.example.com`. How can I have the Servlet container and/or any running servlet *sense* which domain name it is serving?

Comment: Are you asking to know what the "parent" page is? How is the servlet included?

Comment: [getLocalName](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalName%28%29) on ServletRequest should give you what you want.

Comment: @BevynQ - that will return the host name of the machine the application is running on, which may not be the same as the virtual host name. [getServerName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName()) is a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servlet should be able to see the entire request URL:

Method 1: Get the request URL and parse it yourself.

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

Method 2:

```
String server = request.getServerName()
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040094/getting-request-url-in-a-servlet) answer

Answer (score 1):

for Servlets, use the `getServerName()` method on the [request](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29) object.

as far as servlet containers go, if you put apache in front of your container, you can do some chicanery with VHosts.  You will have to look at your specific servlet container's documentation so see if their HTTP servers support something like VHosts at that level.

Answer (score 0):

```
String host = request.getHeader("Host");
```