# How to protect restful webservice from unauhtorised access

Tags: java, web-services, security, rest, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS Restful webservice. This resource/webservice is asset for us. I am exposing this service url to third party client that would call this service resource. I want to protect this service from another authorised client/vendors.

Thus my question is -

How to protect this.

I thought to include an API key and the API key should be matched with a perticuler client API Key. And I also need to match the client url address means from whcih url the request is coming.

How to do this. How to get the URL that is calling the our rest service. I am deploying my rest in Tomcat 7.0.

Thanks

Update --

```
@Path("report")
@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class DnaReportResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void getDnaReport(@Context UriInfo uri) {
        System.out.println(uri.getRequestUri());
        System.out.println(uri.getPath());
        System.out.println(uri.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(uri.getBaseUri());

        //MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uri.getQueryParameters();
        }
}
```

Comment: the apache config probably has more to do with this sort of thing. Unless you aren't running apache and you are just using tomcat.

Comment: @FaddishWorm I am using Tomcat Apache 7.0 server.

Answer (score 0):

From your servlet handler you can call

`String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();`

[Getting request URL in a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040094/getting-request-url-in-a-servlet)

EDIT

did you try

`String url = uri.getRequestUri().toString();`

What does it return?

Comment: How is it possible in restful service resource class in JAX-RS jersey.Folow is example -

public void getReport(@Context UriInfo uri) {
  System.out.println(uri.getRequestUri());
  System.out.println(uri.getPath());
  System.out.println(uri.getAbsolutePath());
  System.out.println(uri.getBaseUri());

 }

Comment: it is returning the whole uri. I already did this. But, it is returning my local uri. Let suppose I am exposing this service url to you and you are calling the my service for your site. Now will i get your site domain name i.e. suppose www.faddishworm.com???

Comment: Hi..did u get my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Tomcat Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html) configuration to achieve authenticate your clients.